# 1.2 led to be used with nokia charger

Tags: led

I bought 1.2 volt , 2 pin, clear LED bulbs. if I try with nokia charger ( which is 3 to 5 volts 100 mA ) it gets fused.Is there any way to use this as i do not have any device of 1.2 volts. Kindly suggest a way.

---

Sir, I think it is of 1.2 volts, as the shop keeper who sold ,  tested with a small button cell , . even with this it was just showing a small faint light . I  bought from a different shop some  led earlier -which they showed with NOKIA cell battery , which is giving reasonable light. So I am confused. I tried to test some of the bought LED with NOKIA cell battery , it gave a flip & then it went dead.
Is there  any way way to find out the voltage of the LED.I am a lay man & do not know electronics. Pl help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resistor and voltage of a circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246566/resistor-and-voltage-of-a-circuit)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Current vs. voltage curves for various LED colours. [Source](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).#*

- LEDs are light emitting diodes.
- Diodes have a "forward voltage drop".
- The forward voltage drop varies with colour as it depends on the make-up of the semiconductor doping to generate the colour.

As Figure 1 shows, there is no LED that passes enough current to give off useful amounts of light at 1.2 V other than, perhaps, an infrared type as used in TV remote controls, etc. It is unlikely that you have a 1.2 V LED.

LEDs require current limiting. The simplest method is to use a series resistor. There are at least a million articles on this on the web. Here's mine: [Ohm's law and resistor calcultation](http://lednique.com/electrical-theory-basics/ohms-law-and-resistor-calculation/).